# Monty Hall In R - setdiff unexpected results

Tags: r, sample, do.call, set-difference

I am writing a program in R to do some simulations of the Monty Hall Problem explained here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Lb-6rxZxx0

Consider this code, `sample(setdiff(doors, c(pick, car)),1)` "should" be 3 every time, but it isn't.

```
doors <- 1:3
pick <- 2
car <- 1
sample(setdiff(doors, c(pick, car)),1)
[1] 3
sample(setdiff(doors, c(pick, car)),1)
[1] 1
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you end up calling `sample.int` since

```r
doors <- 3L
pick <- sample(doors, 1)
car <- sample(doors, 1)
class(setdiff(doors, c(pick, car)))
#R [1] "integer"
```

and

```
length(setdiff(doors, c(pick, car)))
#R [1] 1
```

See `help("sample.int")` or

```
body(sample)
#R {
#R    if (length(x) == 1L && is.numeric(x) && is.finite(x) && x >= 
#R         1) {
#R         if (missing(size)) 
#R            size <- x
#R         sample.int(x, size, replace, prob)
#R     }
#R    else {
#R        ...
```

There is no point in sampling unless you have more than one variable in your set.

Comment: It's in the documentation, I was so focused on setdiff I didn't check sample. From sample documentation: "If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x."

Comment: Right, it just has to be `numeric` and an `integer` as I write above.

Comment: @mks212 Since the rest of `body(sample)` is cut off in this answer, I'll point out the (perhaps obvious) fact that If you want a size 1 sample of a vector `vec` which may or may not be length 1, you can do `vec[sample.int(length(vec), 1)]`, which is what is done in `else{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code I made to solve the problem. I used an if statement to only call sample when necessary, which is the case where the candidate picks the door with the car. I feel the overheard of the extra conditional statement is worth more than the cost of forcing sample to work in a way it wasn't intended.

```
  doors <- 1:3
  trials <- 1000

  games <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:trials, function(i){
    pick <- sample(doors, 1)
    car <- sample(doors, 1)
    #open the door the contestant didn't pick and isn't the car
    open_door <- setdiff(doors, c(pick, car))
    #if pick and car are the same, there are two possible doors to open
    #so pick one at random
    #note, sample will malfunction if there is only 1 int passed to it. See documentation.
    #this is the reason for if statement, only deal with the case where there is more than 
    #one int passed
    if(length(open_door)>1) open_door <- sample(open_door, 1)
    #switch to the door that isn't picked and is closed
    switch_to <- setdiff(doors, c(pick, open_door)) 

    data.frame(pick, car, open_door, switch_to)
  }))

  games$switch_wins <- ifelse(games$switch_to == games$car, 1, 0)
  games$stay_wins <- ifelse(games$pick == games$car, 1, 0)

  cat("Switch wins: ", sum(games$switch_wins)/nrow(games), "Stay wins: ", 
      sum(games$stay_wins)/nrow(games), "\n")
```

Output:

```
Switch wins:  0.672 Stay wins:  0.328
```